# Not able to delete document from Mongodb database with PHP

Tags: php

Could anyone be kind enough, to help me guide why my following code is not deleting a document from gridfs :

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0); 
  $m = new Mongo();
  $db = $m->myDB;
  $gridFS = $db->getGridFS();
  $coll= $db->fs->files;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "Trying to delete the doc. <br />";
    $id = (array("_id" => $_POST["id"]));
    $file = $gridFS->findOne(array("_id" => $id), true);
    $r = $gridFS->delete($id);
    if($r){echo "Document deleted. <br />";}
    }
?>
```

Although, I get echoed 'Document deleted.' but actually the document is not deleted from the gridfs by php. What is wrong with my code, or how can I get rid of unwanted documents including binary files..
Thanks in advance.  -- Vasudev.

Answer (score 0):

`_id` field is not a string in mongodb, it's an object of ObjectId class; instead of

```
$id = (array("_id" => $_POST["id"]));
```

you should use

```
$id = (array("_id" => new MongoId($_POST["id"])));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the response.  However as per Elias Van Ootegem's suggestion above, I tried that also - but futile.  Further, with $id = (array("_id" => $_POST["id"])) I can get the contents of the document perfectly, so I think problem is somewhere else.. thanks anyway again..